# Keras model not predicting with its weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I have loaded my trained model and I am trying to get the activation on the first Conv2D layer. Problem is when I am trying to predict the output for the layer it is clearly given my an incorrect output for some filters in the convolution (most of them) while for a few of them it gives me the correct output based on its weights.

To illustrate this I just feed the network an input with all zeros, therefore, I would expect only to get the biases of each respective layer. The code is the following:

```
import os
import tensorflow
import numpy as np
# Load Trained model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('ViewModel.h5')
model.summary()

# Choose layer
layer_name = 'conv2d'
layer = model.get_layer(name=layer_name)
feature_extractor = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=layer.output)

# Bias of my feature extractor
b_f = feature_extractor.get_weights()[1]

# Predict output (It is supposed to get all bias)
input_map = np.zeros((1, 70, 56, 2)) # tensorflow.zeros((1,70,56,2)) yields the same problem
activation = feature_extractor.predict(input_map)

activation = activation.reshape(68, 54, 32) # Remove the 1 in front (shape is (1, 68, 54, 32)

print('--------------------------------------------------')
print('Bias 0 is: {}'.format(b_f[0]))
print('Activation in filter 0 is: ')
print(activation[:, :, 0]) # First filter
print('--------------------------------------------------')
print('Bias 9 is: {}'.format(b_f[9]))
print('Activation in filter 9 is: ')
print(activation[:, :, 9]) # Tenth filter
print('--------------------------------------------------')
```

But my result is:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 70, 56, 2)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 54, 32)        608       
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d (AveragePo (None, 34, 27, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 25, 16)        4624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 23, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_1 (Average (None, 15, 11, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 2640)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 150)               396150    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 150)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 151       
=================================================================
Total params: 403,853
Trainable params: 403,853
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:10 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7ff629d1f0d0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
--------------------------------------------------
Bias 0 is: -0.7553322911262512
Activation in filter 0 is: 
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
--------------------------------------------------
Bias 9 is: 0.42768770456314087
Activation in filter 9 is: 
[[0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]
 [0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]
 [0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]
 ...
 [0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]
 [0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]
 [0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877 ... 0.4276877 0.4276877 0.4276877]]
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would expect the filter 0 is filled with its bias (-0.7553322911262512) but this is not what is happening... I have tried feeding tf.zeros as well... Maybe it is because of the warning as each time I execute the code the number increases by 1 (No idea what the warning is supposed to mean or if it has anything to do with my problem I have tried searching with no luck, for what I seem to understand this only affect the speed of my code?)

I would appreciate a hand here :)

Comment: Its probably just a ReLU activation in the layer transforming negatives into zeros

Comment: Ups... I have tried and it seems to be the case! Thank you! Sorry for asking quite a silly mistake but I couldn't pinpoint it :)